# Referencing db context class from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, self-reference

I have a class named Users.cs which was created Code first from database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
using BookingsModel;

namespace BookingsModel
{
    public partial class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool IsEmailVerified { get; set; }
        public System.Guid ActivationCode { get; set; }

        public static object ReferenceEquals(bool v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Within my project > Models I have created a folder named Extended and created a Users.cs file in there:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using BookingsModel;

namespace Bookings.Models
{
    public partial class Users
    {
    }
}
```

I have taken extended from the namespace and added partial into the name thinking it would make reference to the db Users class but it has not.

How can I make reference to that class?

Comment: they would need to be in the same namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the extended partial in the same namespace as the original class so change it to `BookingsModel`.

Right now you have them in different namespaces so they are treated like 2 different types because the name of the class includes the namespace.

Note:

If you want the autogenerated class to have a different namespace, DO NOT simply change it because it will be overwritten the next time it is generated. Instead right click on the `.tt` file and choose `Properties` and change the namespace there.

Comment: I have changed the namespace from Bookings.Models to BookingsModel as the other class but it has not made reference?

Comment: @user7623641   What do you mean a reference? Right now if you add a property to the extended class it will be available to both classes. It does not need a reference. Basically the compiler treats them like one class. They are actually one class but spread over different files.